# How to mention an attached file in an e-mail?

Tags: expressions, usage, correspondance

Let's assume somebody is asking me to send back a document by email, for example a CV.
In English, while sending the attached file, I usually write:

> Here you are.

In French, can I write:

> Ici vous avez …

Is this a correct expression? Or should I use another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

« Voici / Voilà. » would be enough or something like « Voici le document que vous m'avez demandé. »

**2017 EDIT:**

There are actually many many ways to go about this.
A more formal and more fancier way to put it would be:

> Vous trouverez (ou Veuillez trouver) ci-joint le document demandé.

Comment: Worth noting the idiom  « le document ci-joint » when referring to the attached document. For instance « […] comme vous pouvez le voir sur la photo ci-jointe. » which means " […] as you can see on the attached pic."

Answer (score 7):

*Voici* est en effet une possiblité mais c'est extrêmement formel. Il y a également la possiblité d'opter pour

> Le voilà. *(assez sobre également mais plus courant)*

voire même (à adapter en fonction de la nature de votre relation avec l'interlocuteur)

> (Et) voilà ! *(plus enjoué/enthousiaste)*

Pour le cas particulier de l'email, on trouve fréquemment aussi la formule :

> [Vous trouverez / Veuillez trouver] [en pièce jointe / ci-joint] [nom du document] ...

Comment: +1 for the "en pièce jointe / ci-joint" idiom.

Answer (score 5):

In another formal way , you can say :

> Veuillez trouver ci-joint le document demandé.