# Usage de « Voici » et de « Voilà »

Tags: choix-de-mot

Après avoir lu [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/ici-vous-avez-quelque-chose) sur le site, et avoir lu les deux réponses qui sont très semblables. Je me suis demandé quelle était l'exacte différence entre l'usage de *Voici* et celui de *Voilà*.

On peut répondre à quelqu'un par les expressions suivantes :

- « Le voilà »
- « Le voici »

Ces deux expressions semblent similaires et avoir relativement le même sens.

Quand doit-on privilégier l'une ou l'autre ? Y a-t-il des cas où l'une peut être utilisée, mais pas l'autre ?

Comment: J'allais te faire la remarque que " versus " était un anglicisme mal à propos, mais une petite recherche sur Internet m'a appris que c'était du bon français désuet et remis au gout du jour grâce à l'anglais. Merci pour cette page de culture que tu m'as involontairement ouverte !

Comment: @Oltarus: Qualifier le latin de français désuet c'est quand même osé.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Héhé, au temps pour moi, j'ai une faute de frappe qui a fourché ma langue et, heu... je te rappelle, je passe dans un tunnel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C'est la même différence qu'entre *ici* et *là* ou *celui-ci* et *celui-là*, etc.

*Ici*, *voici* et *celui-ci* indiquent une proximité.

*Là*, *voilà* et *celui-là* indiquent un éloignement.

**Exemples :**

> Il sortit de sa poche un morceau de papier chiffonné et s'exclama joyeusement : « J'ai une théorie dont voici la preuve. »
>
> En entendant au loin un sifflement bien reconnaissable, Marie se tourna vers son fils et lui dit en souriant : « Voilà le train qui arrive. »

Il peut s'agir d'une distance physique, comme les exemples ci-dessus ou d'une distance temporelle, imaginaire, relationnelle, etc.

> Les deux explorateurs s'approchèrent de la boite de Pandore. Marco prit l'initiative de l'ouvrir.
> — Voici donc le trésor de notre temps.
> — Et voilà les ennuis qui pointent leur nez à l'horizon, ponctua Samuel.

<s>Voici ma réponse ! (et [voilà](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/usage-de-voici-versus-voila) ta question).</s>

 (Désolé, mon expression est incorrecte. Source : [la réponse de mouviciel](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6268/435).

Answer (score 13):

Outre la proximité, *Voici* peut être utilisé pour annoncer quelque chose qui va suivre :

> Voici la marche à suivre : ...

Réciproquement, *Voilà* permet de revenir sur ce qui précède :

> ... Voilà comment j'ai fait.