# « voici » versus « voilà »

Tags: expressions

Je comprends que « voici » et « voilà » marquent respectivement « une proximité » et « un éloignement ». Je me suis renseigné sur la différence d'usage par le biais d'autres questions similaires posées sur ce site et ailleurs, mais je n'arrive toujours pas à expliquer bien leur différence dans les deux cas suivants.

---

« J'hésitais entre le français et l'allemand. Mais il m'a suffi d'un jour pour comprendre que moi et l'allemand... ça fait deux !

> 1A : Me **voici**, content de m'être tourné vers le français ! »
>
> 1B : Me **voilà**, content de m'être tourné vers le français ! »

---

> 2A : **Voici** dix ans que j'habite ici.
>
> 2B : **Voilà** dix ans que j'habite ici.

---

***UPDATE @Laure:***

I wonder if this distinction between "*voilà*" and "*voici*" extends to the expression "*Voilà/Voici pourquoi*"? Once again, I've come up with two example sentences. Do they come across as I intend them to?

> Qu'est-ce que tu n'as pas compris dans « je suis débordé toute la semaine » !?
>
> {sur un ton de reproche} **Voilà pourquoi** je t'ai demandé de cuisiner toi-même !

---

> C'est une jolie petite maison à un saut de puce du bureau.
>
> {sur un ton enthousiaste} **Voici pourquoi** je ne veux pas manquer cette occasion de l'acheter !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La différence entre  *voici* et *voilà*, *ici* et *là*, *ceci* et *celà* expliquée dans les réponses à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6266/358) est formelle. Si elle est tout à fait pertinente quand les paires sont employées dans un même contexte, quand ces mots sont employés séparément de façon informelle, et surtout à l'oral, cette différence est gommée.

En langage courant les deux solutions que tu proposes sont tout à fait admises, surtout si l'on considère que *voilà* est un peu plus fréquent que *voici*. Cependant on peut voir une différence en langage formel. Dans les deux paires de phrases citées en exemple, les critères de choix sont affectifs. *Voici* implique la proximité, l'acceptation, et *voilà*, implique l'éloignement, le rejet.
Il semble paradoxal d'employer *voilà* pour parler d'une situation dont on est content.

> Me voici, content de m'être tourné vers le français !

mais :

> Me voilà, déçu de m'être tourné vers le français.

> Voici dix ans que j'habite ici et je m'y trouve bien.

mais :

> Voilà dix ans que j'habite ici, vivement que je trouve un nouveau logement.

***Update***
On peut établir la même nuance dans les expressions *voici/voilà pourquoi* dans les deux exemples ajoutés à la question.

Comment: The difference in terms of "l'acceptation" or "le rejet" -- this is something I haven't picked up until now. Merci. :)

Comment: To: @Laure     I've just come up with the following two sentences for comparison purposes. Do they sound natural to you? Merci. « ***Voilà** la deuxième fois que mon ordinateur **me lâche** cette semaine.* » versus « ***Voici** deux fois que je **vois une étoile filante** cette nuit.* »

Comment: @LUNA They're correct. In the case of counting something (number of times or duration) using *voici* or *voilà* adds a subjective appreciation that would not be present if you used *c'est...* or *ça fait...* *C'est la deuxième fois que..* *Ça fait deux fois que...*.

Answer (score 2):

Comme cela a déjà été dit, la différence est de moins en moins faite, surtout à l'oral en registre courant. En général "-ci" (comme dans "ceci", "celui-ci", "ce jour-ci"...) se réfère à ce qui est proche et "-là" à ce qui est loin.
On peut voir l'éloignement comme un éloignement affectif (comme celà a été expliqué dans les autres réponses), mais aussi comme un éloignement temporel:

> Me voici, content de m'être tourné vers le français !

Car on parle ici du futur (ce vers quoi on va). Par contre on aurait aussi pu conclure par:

> Et voilà comment j'ai arrêté d'étudier l'allemand.

Ici pas d'ouverture vers l'avenir, seulement une histoire passée qui s'éloigne.

Tu diras:

> Voilà dix ans que j'habite ici.

Si tu projettes de partir, mais plutôt:

> Voici dix ans que je travaille comme dentiste.

Si tu veux expliquer que tu as de l'expérience (tu sous-entends que tu vas continuer à travailler comme dentiste)

Si tu expliques quelque chose, ça dépend de l'ordre dans lequel tu fais tes explications:

> Voici comment on fait un gâteau: commencez par casser trois oeufs, puis ajoutez de la farine.

A cette étape, le cuisinier n'a pas encore fait son gâteau, mais ça ne va pas tarder.

> Terminez par vingt minutes de cuisson, et voilà comment on fait un gâteau.

A cette étape, le gâteau est prêt, la recette est donc terminée.

Answer (score 1):

Un complément historique à la réponse de @Laure. Le latin (dont vient le français) avait 3 mots pour ce/cet:

- hic: ceci (que j'ai, que je vois, etc.) - point du vue du sujet
- iste : cela (que vous avez, que vous voyez, etc.) - point de vue de l'interlocuteur
- ille : ce qui est loin

Ces mots étaient notamment employés dans les plaidoiries. Dans les affaires de meurtres, *ille* désignait la victime (cet homme qui n'est pas là), et *iste* l'accusé (cet homme devant vous). Par extension, *ille* a donné illustre, et *iste* (devenu celui-là) a conservé un sens péjoratif.