# The use of the particle “là”

Tags: sens, démonstratifs

What is the meaning of *"là"* in expressions like

> - à ce moment-là,
> - à ce niveau-là, ... ?

Comment: It's related to the distinction we can make in English with "this/that", in Spanish with "este, ese, aquello", and in French, it's "-là, -ci".

Answer (score 5):

"Là" is an adverb. It's used for time and place.

- Ce moment-là : this precise moment, the "**là**" puts the word "moment" in kind of highlights
- Ce niveau-là : same idea, to put attention about "niveau".

But be carefull with the article "la" without accent

**EDIT:** I would like to add that "-là" is used to show that there is a distance compared to use "-ci".
For exemple, "ces jours-ci" means they are closer than "ces jours-là". You can find a better explanation here: [« voici » versus « voilà »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22266/voici-versus-voil%c3%a0)